Meaning behind the idol of adya Kali?
What is the purpose of adya Kali worship which is present near Dakshineswar temple? What does the idol signify and how is it different from the idol of maa bhavatarini in Dakshineswar? Also why does the temple doors of adyapith opens only for three times in a day? Thank you
